# Removing footer from FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, filemaker

Does anyone know how to remove the footer from Full Calendar so it can stretch all the way to the bottom of the screen? Or at the very least reduce the size of the footer? I'm working in Filemaker and can get the calendar to work just fine but I really have limited space for where it's rendering and would prefer for the calendar to go all the way to the bottom of the web viewer. Currently there's a large gap below the calendar for the footer.

Tried removing all of the components of the footer, but it still renders.

I had tried setting the footer: false, but at the suggestion of another user I also tried setting the footerToolbar: false.  Setting the footerToolbar: false seemed to have no effect whereas setting the footer: false had a marginal effect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gid9v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `footerToolbar` to `false`? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/footerToolbar

```js
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ...,
  initialView: ...,
  headerToolbar: ...,

  footerToolbar: false,

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried something similar by setting the footer: false